# Get count of items in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Using app engine's `endpoints` in my android app I need to get the number of items in the data store based on a filter and return that to my app.

I could do on app engine and then return the results as a collection but I dont need any of that data and just need the number of items.

What would be the appropriate was to achieve this using the Java API since I cannot return primitive types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is returning the count in a CollectionResponse like this

```
public CollectionResponse<Integer> count(@Named("weddingId") String weddingId){
    Query<CloudRecord> query = ofy().load().type(CloudRecord.class).filter("weddingId =",weddingId);
    List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    count.add(query.count());

    return CollectionResponse.<Integer>builder().setItems(count).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `Map<String, Long>`/`Map<String, Integer>` in place of the `long`/`int`. 
As you are using endpoints, you will be easily able to acess these values using the key that you push into the map.
If not using the endpoints, you will get this Map as a json object in the response, just look for the relevant key in the response json.